# Shared NSURLCache and UIWebView on iOS 8

Tags: uiwebview, ios8, nsurlcache

In iOS 7, I was able to set a shared URL cache to a subclass of `NSURLCache` and any `UIWebView`s I created would automatically use that shared cache for each request.

```
// Set the URL cache and leave it set permanently
ExampleURLCache *cache = [[ExampleURLCache alloc] init];
[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:cache];
```

However, now in iOS 8 it doesn't seem like UIWebView pulls from the shared cache and `cachedResponseForRequest` never gets called.

Has anyone found documentation for this change, or a workaround?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had same problem today. It was ok on ios7 and broken on ios8.

The trick is to create your own cache as the first thing you do in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // IMPORTANT: call this line before anything else. Do not call [NSURLCache sharedCache] before this because that
    // creates a reference and then we can't create the new cache.
    NSURLCache *URLCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:4 * 1024 * 1024 diskCapacity:20 * 1024 * 1024 diskPath:nil];

    [NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:URLCache];

...
```

You can see this being done in other apps:

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/Example/AppDelegate.m

This site, while old, has more info on why you shouldn't even call [NSURLCache sharedInstance] before the above code:
http://inessential.com/2007/02/28/figured_it_the_heck_out

Comment: Cool, I ended up fixing my specific issue by using another approach involving implementing a custom `NSURLProtocol`. If anyone wants to see the code just mention me here and I'll add it.